# Filter on/Order by Postgres range type in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

SQLAlchemy supports Postgres range types, as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#range-types). It uses the `postgresql+psycopg2` dialect for Postgres communication. [These testcases](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/55eacc8dbea3c3f98197bde9034fd6558fb2bc09/test/dialect/postgresql/test_types.py?at=master#cl-1378) give usage examples for the range types in SQLALchemy.

How can I filter by, or order by, one component (lower or upper) of such a range field in SQLAlchemy?

Using the example from the first link

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeRange
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TSRANGE

class RoomBooking(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'room_booking'

  room = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
  during = Column(TSRANGE())

booking = RoomBooking(
  room=101,
  during=DateTimeRange(datetime(2013, 3, 23), None)
)
```

I would, e.g., like to filter on bookings with a during that begins on a given datetime or order the bookings by the start of the datetime.

As such I'm looking to generate roughly this SQL:

```
SELECT room, during
FROM room_booking
WHERE lower(during) = foo
ORDER BY upper(during)
```

I have tried constructs like

```
RoomBooking.query.filter(RoomBooking.during.lower == foo).order_by(RoomBooking.during.upper)
```

but recognize that this is likely not working because lower is an attribute on the python object and not associated with the underlying table column.

One possible solution to this might be finding a way to use the [`upper()/lower()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) range functions from SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to use the already existing `func.lower()/func.upper()` methods in sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
RoomBooking.query.filter(func.lower(RoomBooking.during) == foo).order_by(func.upper(RoomBooking.during))
```

These methods were probably introduced to support (un)capitalizing text – it would be interesting to see if other unavailable postgres functions can be implemented in a similar manner as well.

Comment: To be fair, I think the `func`s are actually there to support calling database functions from sqlalchemy. Which means that this is probably a totally legitimate use, because postgres has an `upper` function defined for both strings (which uppercases them) and ranges (which returns the upper bound of the range). And a `lower`, which does the opposite, of course.